# Bones rotate after adding IK

Tags: rigging

I am new to rigging (I am new to Blender as well, but my modelling is better then my rigging.) Hope you can help me with this.
So when I add Inverse Kinematics to the bones I am pointing below, the bones rotate. Also while moving the targets, the knees don't bend soon enough. Later I tried to align the bones from front view axis but nothing has changed. Also here is the [Blender File](https://we.tl/t-grRrCbzH5x). Thanks in advance.

[image: edit mode left, pose mode right]

Comment: have you tweaked your pole angle?

Comment: I have tried it. But since there was no change I left it untweaked.  However, I have left the rotation box enabled so appearantly that was the problem. Unchecking it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *IK* constraint, disable *Rotation*, give it a *Pole Angle* of about 6,5° and it seems to work. Also, don’t forget to disable the *Deform* option of the *IK* controlers and targets.

[image]

Comment: I tried disabling rotation and it works indeed. I  have rigged this again yesterday and there were no problems. So after seeing your answer I went to that file and checked the rotation and it was disabled from the start. Thank you for the answer.